# Why i can't save anything in my mocked repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-data-jpa

I'm learning testing in spring boot, i have this test:

```
 @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
 @SpringBootTest
class AppUserServiceTest {

@Mock
private UserRepository repository;
private UserService userService;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    userService = new UserService(repository);
}


@Test
void itShouldLoadUsernameByName() {
    AppUser appUser = new AppUser(
            ApplicationRole.USER,
            "leonardo",
            "rossi",
            "leo__",
            "a@gmail.com",
            "password"
    );

    repository.save(appUser);

    userService.loadUserByUsername(appUser.getUsername());
    verify(repository).searchByUserName(appUser.getUsername());

}

}
```

it keep throwing me an exception because it doesn't find any user in the database, in fact even if i save the user the repository.findAll() return 0 element.

This is my User service that i'm trying to test:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService
    implements UserDetailsService {

private final UserRepository repository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return repository.searchByUserName(username)
            .orElseThrow(
                    ()-> new UsernameNotFoundException("The username " + username + " has not been found")
            );
}
```

This is my H2 databse for testing configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: do you understand what mocking is? It seems that's where your confusion starts

Comment: you mock something when is needed for a complex object and has already been tested like a repository

Comment: yes, but do you actually understand what mocking is? Not when to apply it.

Comment: simulated object that simulate the behavior of an object (i think) but are not the real one

Comment: indeed, keyword: simulated; You don't write (save) to the db, you merely simulate. so: it's quite normal that nothing is saved. You should not call your repository from within your test, you just need to tell your mock how to behave when it is called within your service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mock is just a mock. It's never actually doing something. It just can behave like a real thing, but you have to tell the mock how to do it.

So if you mock the UserRepository and try to save something nothing will happen. Because again, a mock never actually does something. The advantage of this is that you don't actually need the whole infrastructure to unit test a tiny method. Additionally the test gets independent of data. What you can do now is return some data if some method is called.

In your case, you don't need a whole database to test the functionality of the UserService. Thus mocking the repository is a good option. Now since it's a mock you have to tell the mock how to behave for your test case:

```
@Test
void itShouldLoadUsernameByName() {
    AppUser appUser = new AppUser(
            ApplicationRole.USER,
            "leonardo",
            "rossi",
            "leo__",
            "a@gmail.com",
            "password"
    );

    when(standortRepository.searchByUserName(any())).thenReturn(appUser);

    userService.loadUserByUsername(appUser.getUsername());

    //More expectations ...

    verify(repository).searchByUserName(appUser.getUsername());    
}
```

Now what I have done is to tell the mock it should return the appUser, when the Method `searchByUserName` is called.

P.s. these are the static imports I used:

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
```